# Remove spaces/lines between rows in GXT Grid

Tags: gxt

[image: My problem]

My goal is to create a solid line between certain columns of a Grid.  To accomplish this, I've done the following to the appropriate column:

```
ColumnConfig colConfig = new ColumnConfig("myID", "My Col Title", 50);
colConfig.setStyle("border-right:solid medium black;");
```

As you can see from the attached picture, the rows seem to have spaces between them that is preventing my column border from being a solid line going down.  Can anyone help with either eliminating these lines between rows, or some alternative to accomplish my goal?

I see there is a method provided on the Grid type itself to turn on/off column lines:

```
grid.setColumnLines(false);
```

But I don't see anything for rows.  I also don't know whether even for columns that method is hiding the lines or actually removing them - I suspect the former.

Thanks in advance for any and all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I did this by using a little string manipulation heres how;

Create yourself a GridView (extending Grid View) and override the following

```
protected String doRender(List<ColumnData> cs, List<ModelData> rows, int startRow, int colCount, boolean stripe) {
        String grab = super.doRender(cs, rows, startRow, colCount, stripe);
        grab = grab.replace("style=\"", "style=\"border:0px none; ");
         return grab;
```

}

```
    protected String renderRows(int startRow, int endRow) {
        String grab = super.renderRows(startRow, endRow);
        grab = grab.replace("style=\"", "style=\"border:0px none; ");
        return grab;
    }
```

this will strip out any borders in grid as its rendered

hope it helps

Comment: That's clever, thanks.  However, it leaves me with 2 problems.  First, I neglected to mention I'm using a GroupSummaryView, so the top (group name) row in each group remains borderless - apparently, the ColumnConfig settings don't apply to that row.  Second, it would still be nice to see the grid lines, just to have the column border paint over the intersecting row grid lines it passes through.  Not complaining, just saying it doesn't quite work for what I wanted.  :)

Comment: To do that you would have to re-implement the borders within your render as what is being remove is a border on the row itself (which is y it intersects your border) so re-implementing it on a cell by cell basis would help you choose where the borders go

Answer (score 0):

the border is defined for the class `.x-grid3-row` (applied on the div-element for the row), so you can just override this in a custom .css-file or delete the corresponding line from your gxt-all.css (i'd recommend the first method, because the gxt-all.css could change with future gxt versions, overwriting your changes)